# Unexpected behavior of a Modal View displaying a YouTube video in a UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, youtube, xcode4.2, modalviewcontroller, gdata

I have a view based application (no storyboards) with a button that presents a modal view with a webview in it. The webview loads a YouTube video and the user taps it and watches the video in full screen.

When the video ends (or the user taps "done"), the video player dismisses, but for some reason I see the Main View instead of the modal view controller (and I can't invoke the modal view again with the button, although the IBAction is being called)...

The present modal view code (in the Main View controller):

```
SomeViewController *controller = [[[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
                controller.delegate = self;
                controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
                [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Then, in "SomeViewController", I have a UIWebView that loads the YouTube video:

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
```

The video plays just fine, but when it's done, it's get dismissed and the Main View is being showed instead of the Modal View (SomeViewController).
No error is being given though.

From what I understand, the video player is also a modal view, so the hierarchy is something like this:

```
-- Main View
---- Modal View (SomeViewController with WebView)
-------- Video Modal View (invoked by the WebView)
```

So I don't get why is the Main View controller being shown after the Video is done playing, and why it doesn't let me invoke the modal view controller again...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I did a workaround by adding a Navigation Controller to the AppDelegate and using pushViewController instead of a Modal View... I tried to invoke a Nav Controller in a modal view, but it had the same issue.

Comment: Did you encounter the problem of the webview showing up blank ever?

Comment: magtak: in the simulator it will show up blank, because the YouTube plugin is not present. But on the device it shouldn't show up blank.

Comment: Exactly the same issue here. I made a simple demo, and this may be an iOS's bug. https://github.com/inamiy/ModalYoutubeIOS5Bug